# Find and prove some needed conditions on $m,n$ for the complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$ to have...

Tags: graph-theory

**Question:**

> Find and prove some needed conditions on $m,n$ for the complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$ to have:
>
> 1. An eulerian circuit.
> 2. A hamilton cycle.

**Attempt:**

I've conjectured that $K_{m,n}$ has an eulerian circuit if and only if it has a hamilton cycle, I have no idea  how to prove that, but that would imply that the conditions I find would work for both points.

A condition I thought of was that since the graph is bipartite, all it's cycles must have even length, so $m+n$ should be even, right?

How would you go about solving these kinds of questions? Could you guys give me some tips?

Answer (score 2):

Your conjecture is incorrect. It might help to review the definitions of Eulerian circuit and Hamilton cycles and then draw some examples to get clues for the necessary conditions.

For example, let me tell you that $K_{2,4}$ is Eulerian but it is *not* Hamiltonian. Why? Well you can just find an Eulerian circuit by hand. But now try to find a Hamiltonian cycle. You'll notice that any such cycle would have to alternate from one side to the other and so...

This should give you a hint for the general case. What *must* $m$ be compared to $n$ in order for a Hamilton cycle to exist? Once you figure this out, make sure to show that the condition you found is also sufficient, i.e., that there is indeed a Hamilton cycle in the $K_{m,n}$ in which $m,n$ satisfy the condition you found.

About the Eulerian circuit part, well if $n$ or $m$ is zero, then there is trivially an Eulerian circuit. If neither are zero, then $K_{m,n}$ is connected and the famous theorem to know is that an Eulerian circuit exists if and only if every vertex has even degree. Now what are the degrees of the vertices of $K_{m,n}$ (there are two possibilities)? So now what must conditions must $m$ and $n$ satisfy for there to be an Eulerian circuit, in view of that famous theorem?